# Multiplying two columns with lists in a for loop

Tags: python

I have the following function:

```
def get_decay_weights(df, stat, col_list):
    df = df.reset_index()
    results_dict = []
    for i,row in df.iterrows():
        year_numbers = len(row['Year'])
        max_stat = max(row[stat])
        if max_stat == 0:
            equal_weights = 1/year_numbers
            weights = {f's{i+1}': equal_weights for i in range(year_numbers)}
        else:
            decay = {f's{i+1}': [] for i in range(year_numbers)}
            percent_stat = {f's{i+1}': [] for i in range(year_numbers)}
            if year_numbers >= 1:
                decay[list(decay)[-1]] = 1
                percent_stat[list(percent_stat)[0]] = (row[stat][0]/max_stat)
            if year_numbers >= 2:
                decay[list(decay)[-2]] = 0.63
                percent_stat[list(percent_stat)[1]] = (row[stat][1]/max_stat)
            if year_numbers >= 3:
                decay[list(decay)[-3]] = 0.63**2
                percent_stat[list(percent_stat)[2]]= (row[stat][2]/max_stat)
            if year_numbers >= 4:
                decay[list(decay)[-4]] = 0.63**3
                percent_stat[list(percent_stat)[3]] = (row[stat][3]/max_stat)
            cumulative_scores = {k: decay[k]*percent_stat[k] for k in decay}
            weights = {k:v/sum(cumulative_scores.values(), 0.0) for k,v in cumulative_scores.items()}
        for col in col_list:
            combined = [x * y for x, y in zip(list(weights.values()), list(row[col]))]
            print("Combined:", combined)
            df[f'{col}_weighted'] = df.apply(
                lambda row: [x * y for x, y in zip(list((weights.values())), list(row[col]))],axis=1)
            print(df[f'{col}_weighted'] )
    return df

df = get_decay_weights(df, stat = 'Studying Time', col_list=['Math', 'Science'])
```

The values when I print out Combined are correct.

However, the resulting data frame is incorrect when I try add those values to the data frame using the following function:

`df[f'{col}_weighted'] = df.apply(lambda row: [x * y for x, y in zip(list((weights.values())), list(row[col]))],axis=1)`

Through debugging, I learned that in every iteration the list((weights.values()) from that iteration are being multiplied to all previous row[col]. So, in the last iteration, only the last row is correct and all the previous row[col] are being multiplied by the weights in the last iteration.

I know that this is because in the df apply lamdba function, row is not referenced in the list((weights.values()), but is apart of list(row[col]).

I cannot figure out how to fix this function properly. I thought about assigning the result of combined iteratively to the index, but couldn't figure this approach out either.

Edit:

Sample input data:

| Person | Year | Studying Time | Math | English | Science |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Steve | [1,2,3,4,5] | [400,478,512,517,810] | [95,93,94,89,92] | [96,97,92,82,83] | [92,94,97,93,80] |
| George | [1,2] | [379,500] | [89,91] | [92,87] | [75,82] |
| Charles | [1] | [545] | [87] | [89] | [92] |
| Andy | [1, 2, 3] | [510,560,801] | [92,94,97] | [89,89,82] | [79,78,91] |

Interpreting this table, George took the exams two times. He studied 379 minutes on his first exam attempt and 500 minutes on his second exam attempt. He got a 89 on Math on his first attempt and a 91 on his second attempt.

What I am achieving with the code above:

- Assigning decay to each attempt. Your last attempt is worth 1, previous attempt is worth (0.63), previous attempt is worth (0.7)^2, previous attempt is worth (0.63)^3, and the previous attempt is worth (0.63)^4. Students can take the exam once or up to 5 times.
- Calculate the percent of max studying time by dividing the individual attempt's studying time / the attempt with the most studying time
- Multiply the decay of the attempt by the percent of total max studying time for the attempt to get a cumulative variable
- Divide the cumulative variable for one attempt by the sum of all the attempt's cumulative numbers to get the weights.

The final step is to multiply the list of weights by the list of scores in the table and produce a column with these results. This is the code step that I am struggling with.

Comment: Hi, could you provide some sample input data and expected result? I'm having a hard time grasping the objective of the function and think it could be refactored. Thanks

Comment: @Dodd-learning I added some more information. Let me know what you think.

Comment: Hi @bangbanggggg. A few things: It looks like your function isn't the same that you are calling at the end 'get_weights' vs 'get_decay_weights' Is that the right function? If so it doesn't look like the stat parameter is defined for it. In order for us to help it would be beneficial if your function would run without error on the sample data you provided (unless you are trying to figure out why it won't run). 

That way we can be sure everyone has the same input / output before making changes.

Comment: @Dodd-learning fixed it! Sorry about that